# Set limits of ComplexHeatmap legend in R

Tags: r, legend, complexheatmap

I'm working in R using the library(ComplexHeatmap). How would I manually set the legend to go from 0 -> 100 (%)? My actual data only ranges from about 0-40%.

```
df <- matrix((rnorm(100)^2)*9, nrow = 10)

rg<-brewer.pal(n = 8, name = "RdYlGn")

Heatmap(as.matrix(round(df, digits = 1)),
        cluster_rows = FALSE,
        cluster_columns = FALSE,
        col = rev(rg),
        rect_gp = gpar(col = "black"),
        row_title_gp = gpar(fontsize = 7),
        heatmap_legend_param = list(title = "% cover"))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `at` argument inside the list passed to th `heatmap_legend_param` argument

```r
library(ComplexHeatmap)
library(RColorBrewer)

set.seed(1)

df <- matrix((rnorm(100)^2) * 6, nrow = 10)

rg<-brewer.pal(n = 8, name = "RdYlGn")

Heatmap(as.matrix(round(df, digits = 1)),
        cluster_rows = FALSE,
        cluster_columns = FALSE,
        col = rev(rg),
        rect_gp = gpar(col = "black"),
        row_title_gp = gpar(fontsize = 7),
        heatmap_legend_param = list(title = "% cover", at = seq(0, 100, 10)))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-07-21 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>